# What does [cs] means in DDL for MariaDb

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a DDL for a table

```
create table AIRPORT (
    AIRP_CODE varchar(10)[cs] not null,
    AIRP_NAME nvarchar(60)[cs] not null,
    GEOR_ID_LOCATED integer not null,
    PRCC_CONST integer,
    AIRP_TIME_ZONE char(5),
    AIRP_TRANSLATION mediumtext,
    LCOUNT integer default 0
);
```

I am trying to figure out what does [cs] mean in it. I think its for collation but I am not sure how it works. Table DDL isn't written by me and I can't figure it out.

Comment: `cs` probably means case sensitive, but I cannot find any documentation reference to the syntax being used here.

Comment: same here. I know it means case sensitive but can't find any reference for it.

Comment: Does this code even run against MariaDB?

Comment: Hey I tried running this on mariadb and mysql. But it is showing error. Is this working for you ? Tried on mariadb 10.4.11 and mysql 5.6.22

Comment: Nope. Not working for me either but the guy said its working for him. Can't figure out how. Can't see any example.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can this be related to this? 
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/engine-defined-new-tablefieldindex-attributes/

Answer (score 1):

In that position would be `CHARACTER SET` and/or `COLLATION`.

An "airport code" would best be `CHARACTER SET ascii`.  Depending on whether you want to allow case folding, you could use `COLLATION ascii_bin` (disallow folding) or `COLLATION ascii_ci` (allow folding).

For the airport name, it would probably be best to use `UTF-8`:

```
AIRP_NAME varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATION utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci not null
```

Note:  `NVARCHAR` is a notation from non-MySQL vendors; for MySQL the sharset is important.

Perhaps you also want to specify a charset for `AIRP_TRANSLATION`?  Again, utf8mb4 is probably appropriate.

(I have never seen "[cs]"; my advice is aimed at what *should* be specified in that context.)

Answer (score 0):

That SQL code is invalid, period.

You must be missing information. Wherever you got the code from, there's possibly some documentation that explains what it is and how to use it. If it was handed to you by some other person, he didn't consider sharing the information with you.

Judging from column names and types, I suspect the code comes from the README file of an airport database available for download, perhaps in CSV format, and it's just a recommended table structure you are meant to take as starting point and adapt to your own system. My educated guess about `[cs]` is that it's an annotation to imply that those fields are case sensitive, meaning that you application should use e.g. `MAD` and not `mad`.

In any case, having no further context it's impossible to tell.